Flink reads Kafka, why the speed fluctuates significantly when there's backpressure
I have a Flink job that consumes from Kafka, and the task runs stably when the Kafka throughput is <= 1000 messages per second.
If the Kafka throughput exceeds 1000, for example at 1100, Flink experiences backpressure, at which point the consumption rate of Flink fluctuates significantly. Even after the Kafka throughput drops back below 1000 shortly afterward, it takes Flink a considerable amount of time to stabilize its consumption rate again.
I can understand the situation where Flink experiences backpressure when the Kafka throughput exceeds 1000, as this is due to insufficient machine resources.
What I don't understand is that with the same Flink cluster and the same Flink job, even under backpressure, the consumption rate of Flink should remain relatively stable, right? Since the hardware resources have not changed.
Could someone please give some explanations?
BTW, my Flink job doesn't enable checkpoint, and it uses processing time.
